# Navigation Controller Toolbar Buttons issue - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I'm trying to add some button to the toolbar of my navigationController: i see the toolbar, but without the buttons. This is the portion of my code where I set the toolbar...

(this is my AppDelegate)

```
// Create a table view controller
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]
                                              initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;
    rootViewController.entityName = @"County";

    //Navigation Controller
    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                     initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;


    //Barbuttons
    UIBarButtonItem *homeButton;
    homeButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"         Inizio         " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(home)] autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
    barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"  Funzioni online   " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(caricamappa)] autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *creditsButton;
    creditsButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"credits2.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(credits)] autorelease];    

    NSArray *baritems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: homeButton, barButton, creditsButton, nil];

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:baritems];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];


    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [rootViewController release];
    [aNavigationController release];
```

Any idea about my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You should add buttons to navigationItem property of your rootViewController, not to the toolbar of navigation controller.
Something like:

```
rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/toolbar), especially this part:

> Management of this toolbar’s contents is done through the custom view
>   controllers associated with this navigation controller. For each view
>   controller on the navigation stack, you can assign a custom set of
>   toolbar items using the setToolbarItems:animated: method of
>   UIViewController.